# After successful order is placed, how to extract success response via php url components

Tags: php, string, parsing

How to After successful transactions is placed in a payment gateway merchants needs to receive and use  "success" or "failure" message.
Successpage looks like

```
pay.site.com/success.php?q=success&orderid=9615364&amount=1000.0&gatewayreferenceid=0004Q1S3438943
```

PROVIDED:

Merchant gateway developer pdf has  a HTML form to input amount,merchant,order id, gateway reference id
and to retrieve response:

Success Response:

```
<response>
<response_code> Success </response_code>

</response>
```

Failure Response:

```
<response> <response_code> failure </response_code> </response>
```

Now how to get the response ? Via php url parse or this method .
There is another similar url where i need to get two variables from the url and save it . How to do this in curl or soap or PHP form method.

Comment: it's xml. parse it with [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: I was testing with this code: didnt work. Now how to do in DOM